# Euler-Poincare characteristic of $L \otimes Sym^k(\Omega^1_S)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $S$ be a smooth complex rational surface, and $L$ be an ample line bundle on $S$.

I want to compute the Euler-Poincare characteristic of $L \otimes Sym^k(\Omega^1_S)$,
i.e., $$\chi(S, L \otimes Sym^k(\Omega^1_S)),  \ \ k > 0.$$

How can I calculate this value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume $S$ is projective (always good to emphasize). Do you know Riemann-Roch?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I want to calculate this value when $S$ is blow-ups of some Hirzebruch surface.
I checked Riemann-Roch formula. 
Since we have $rank (L \otimes Sym^k (\Omega^1_S) ) = k + 1$,
$$ \chi (S, V) = \frac{1}{2}(c_1(V) \cdot (c_1(V) - c_1(K_S)) - c_2(V) + k + 1.$$
(Here, I put $V = L \otimes Sym^k (\Omega^1_S)$ )

$c_1(V) = c_1(Sym^k(\Omega^1_S)) + (k+1) \cdot c_1(L) = c_1(Sym^k(\Omega^1_S)) + d(k + 1)$,

$c_2(V) = c_2( Sym^k(\Omega^1_S)) + dk c_1(Sym^k(\Omega^1_S)) + (1/2)k(k+1)d^2$.

So, I have to know $c_1(Sym^k(\Omega^1_S))$ and $c_2(Sym^k(\Omega^1_S))$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, you need to know how to calculate Chern classes of symmetric powers. The surefire way to do this (albeit, sometimes tedious) is to use splitting principle and Whitney's theorem Let me illustrate.

If $E$ is a vector bundle, say of rank $r$, splitting principle says, you can pretend it is a direct sum of line bundles, $L_i$ and thus the Chern polynomial is, $c_t(E)=\prod c_t(L_i)$ and $c_t(L_i)=1+c_1(L_i)t$. (Be careful, that $L_i$'s are virtual).

So, if you want to calculate, say the Chern polynomial of $S^2E$ of a rank 2 vector bundle on a surface (as an illustration), by our pretense, we assume $E$ is a direct sum of two line bundles, $L,M$ with $c_1(L)=a, c_1(M)=b$. Then $c_1(E)=a+b, c_2(E)=ab$.

$S^2E$ is then a direct sum of $L^2, L\otimes M, M^2$, whose first Chern classes are $2a, a+b, 2b$.Thus $c_t(S^2E)=(1+2at)(1+(a+b)t)(1+2bt)$. You can expand this and write it in terms of $c_i(E)$ (no $a,b$). I hope the method is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Do $a, b$ not need  to be  integers in practice?
($a + b, ab \in \mathbb{Z}$, though.)

Comment: @Y.M. $a,b$ are virtual, treat them as unknown variables for the calculations.

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you for your detailed explanation! 
I got
$$c_1(Sym^k(\Omega^1_S)) = \frac{1}{2}k(k+1)c_1(\Omega^1_S),$$
$$c_2(Sym^k(\Omega^1_S)) = \frac{1}{24}(k-1)k(k+1)(3k+2)(c_1(\Omega^1_S))^2
+\frac{1}{6}k(k+1)(k+2)c_2(\Omega^1_S).$$